# Is there any way to get round figure value in flutter

Tags: flutter

need to round with nearer value

5680 - should be rounded as 6000 (nearer value)

9450 - should be rounded as 9000

....

I have seen similar questions in stack flow questions but those are not solving my requirements

Comment: Divide the value by 1000 if they are all four digit values, then you can use the available Math standard package in flutter and then perform ceil or floor operation, and once done, multiply back the value with 1000, the floor and ceil will always yield a different result, so you can compare the value after the decimal point to 0.5 and apply floor if  < 0.5 and ceil if > 0.5

Comment: @SARANSURYA what if I want to round 949750 - 900000

Comment: simple, you will have to divide and multiply by the 1 followed by the length of the numbers - 1 times (0) :: ex : 949750 you will have to divide by (100000). Also make sure you work under the MAX_INT range

Comment: See my answer, you can use it on any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import 'dart:math';

int getRound(int num){
    int power = num.toString().length - 1;
    var p = num / pow(10, power);
    num = int.parse(p.toStringAsFixed(0)) * pow(10, power).toInt();
    return num;
    
}
print("NUM " + getRound(949750).toString());
```

results

```
NUM 900000
```

Answer (score 0):

Devide the value

5680/1000=5.68*100=568

Now check the value if it is greater than 500 then pick out the first digit and increase the value by 1 amd multiply by 1000 else pick that first value and multiply by 1000.